# Запятая в предложении: «Гляди, какая собака...»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

В предложении «Гляди, какая собака...» нужна запятая?

Comment: Странно смотрится многоточие в конце этого предложения. Возможно, многоточие показывает, что предложение приведено не полностью. В противном случае должет стоять восклицательный знак.

Answer (score 3):

**Гляди, какая собака...**

Запятая ставится.

Предложение можно рассматривать **как СПП с придаточным изъяснительным,** местоименное прилагательное ***какой*** имеет значение эмоциональной оценки и используется в качестве союзного слова.

Answer (score 3):

Запятая нужна. Относительное местоимение **какой** в этом предложении делает акцент на качестве и свойствах предмета, подчиняет придаточное предложение главному.
*Не знаю, какую вам книгу дать. Он не знает, какая дорога туда ведёт.*
[КАКОЙ](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9)

В главном предложении пропущено (но подразумевается) подлежащее, в придаточном — сказуемое.
[Ты] *Гляди, **какая** собака...* (Какая-то особенная собака или в особых условиях.)

*Ой, Вань, гляди, какие клоуны!..  Ой, Вань, гляди, какие карлики!* (В. Высоцкий)
 *Гляди, какой закат чудесный!* (А. Гарипов)